# how to move an overriden method to a a separate file

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

see this example

```
class MainController extends GetxController {
 @override
 void OnInit() {
  // some code    
 super.onInit();
 }}
```

what's the best way if I want to move the OnInit() to a separate file so it doesn't show in the `MainController` but works as if it's there?

is this possible in any way with extensions methods or mixin
Please, share your ideas with me !

Comment: This is not possible.  Why do you want this?

Comment: I want to separate those methods to seaparate files

Comment: That's *what* you want to do, not *why* you want to do it.  You say that you don't want the overridden method to "show" in `MainController`, but it's a part of the base class interface, so that does not make sense.

Comment: As an example for why *why* matters, maybe you want to do it because you want to reuse your `MainController` class across multiple projects and are attempting to conditionally override some method.  Or maybe your `MainController` class is very large and you want to just reduce some clutter.  Understanding *why* will allow people to provide alternative solutions that might satisfy your ultimate goal.